# Pyramid not included in Python virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyramid

I'm an experienced developer, but not very familiar with Python and Pyramid.

I'm trying to follow some (a bit old and unclear) instructions on deploying a Pyramid web application. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

The instructions say to install virtualenv and Pyramid - I do so with `apt install virtualenv` and `apt install python-pyramid`. Then they say I should run the app in a virtual environment, so I build that with `virtualenv . -ppython3`, and activate it with `source bin/activate`. I install the application from a ready-to-run buildout from GitHub. The buildout includes a "production.ini" file with parameters to pserve.

But Pyramid is not included in the virtual environment built with virtualenv. (There is no "pserve" in the bin directory, e.g.) So I can't run the applications with `bin/pserve etc/production.ini`, as the instructions say. And if I try with only "pserve", I get errors when trying to access files like "var/waitress-%(process_num)s.sock". Files that the app excepts to find in the virtual environment.

I've looked for flags to tell virtualenv to include Pyramid, but couldn't find any. Am I overlooking something? I'd be most grateful for some help! :-)

/Anders from Sweden

Comment: See the official docs for guidance. Requirements cover... requirements. https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might want to try installing Pyramid in your virtual environment using pip, since apt-installed libraries are installed into `/opt`, rather than being visible to Python. In the guide, it seems like you're wanting to install Pyramid through the virtual environment so that it can be used by your program, so I think you'd be best using pip rather than apt-get. I did a quick Google search, and it seems like [this](https://pypi.org/project/pyramid/) is the library you need. Here, all you'd have to do is run the installation command once you've already entered the virtual environment with `pip install pyramid`. This way, you should only have access to it within the virtual environment, as well!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it's using buildout - I assume this is zc.buildout. buildout usually manages its own virtualenv and handles installing all of the necessary dependencies. It really depends on how that buildout is configured as there's no standard there for what to do or how to run your app. I would normally expect pserve to be exposed in the `bin` folder, but maybe another app-specific script is exposed instead.